# System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox text is missing

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with Visual Studio 2005 (C#) and in one of my windows forms I have a couple of textboxes. I have placed the textboxes inside instances of 'System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox' because I want to use the GroupBox member 'Text' to tell what the textboxes are for (it shows up as a label near the top left corner of the fine line that encircles the GroupBox).

My problem is that suddenly one of these labels just disappeared. It is present when I work with the form in the designer but when I run the program and the form appears the label is gone.

Thank you for any information on this issue!

Comment: Please post your Form_Load event code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to be sure you're not setting the .Text property of the GroupBox to an empty string.

Comment: Oops! You are right! I had mistakenly cleared the groupbox text instead of the textbox text. Reckless use of the editor's auto-complete functionality on my behalf. Thank you for your answer, it helped me find my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to access the groupbox in your code you can always set the property GenerateMember on the groupbox to false and what you see in the editor "should" always be what you get when you run the app.

This is useful with any controls that you do not wish to modify during runtime thus keeping your memory allocation down as well as mistakenly modifying one of it's properties as well.