# Cannot get button text to be displayed Visual Studio 2015 pro - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am having a strange problem with visual studio, I cannot get my button's text to be displayed when the button is within a group box.

It happens to any button that I try. It doesn't matter if I create the button inside of the 
group box or outside of the group box, Once the button is in the group box it looses it's text.

[image: Button in group box]

When the button is created outside of the group box you can see the text just fine.
[image: Button with Text being displayed properly]

I have tried the following

- Bringing the button to the front
- Pushing the group box to the back
- Changing the buttons appearance

**The properties for the button are:**

[image: Button's properties]

*NOTE:* There are no events setup with the button nor is it being referenced by my code.

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915387/system-windows-forms-groupbox-text-is-missing

Comment: Have you saved the project, closed it, restarted VS, then opened the project? I have had similar issues with various versions of VS and saving then restarting everything sometimes helps.

Comment: Could you change that ForeColor property to something like WindowText or just Black?

Comment: @Steve I have changed my background color to Button Default and it still is not working.

Comment: @Steve I see the text on the top button. Super hard though... I think you are right. Change the ForeColor.

Comment: @TimFreese Thank you but no that would not be the case because I have not referred to the button inside of my code yet,

Comment: If you take a photo app and look at your image and zoom in, you see "BUTTON TEXT" in Control-Light color.

Comment: It appears I mixed up the colors and Set the fore-color to what I wanted the background color to be. Thank you @LarsTech and @ Steve for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the button is inheriting the forecolor of the groupbox. Move the button to the GroupBox, then select the button and change the forecolor to what you want it to be.